# DStream filtering and offset management in Spark Streaming Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am currently writing a Spark streaming application that reads data from Kafka and tries to decode it before applying some transformations.

The current code structure looks like this:

```
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](...)
 .map(record => decode(record.value())
 .filter(...)
 .foreachRDD { rdd =>
   val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
   ...
   stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
 }
```

The decoding and filtering of failures happens on the DStream, and the offset management is done inside the `foreachRDD`, which means that I will only commit successful records.

To commit the failed records, I could move everything inside the `foreachRDD` loop:

```
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](...)
 .foreachRDD { rdd =>
   val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
   ...
   // Decoding and filtering here
   ...
   stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
 }
```

However, I am wondering whether there is another way to commit the failed records. Maybe it would be acceptable to not commit the failed records?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the spark-streaming-kafka library.

Reading the documentation of [offset Ranges](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-streaming/spark-streaming-kafka-HasOffsetRanges.html) it stores the *range* of offsets from the topic partitions. It does not *filter out* or mark individual offsets within that range based on the clients filtering ".filter(…)" actions. So if you commit that offsetRanges it will commit the highest offset number per partition, regardless of your filter actions.

That makes sense, as your Consumer is telling the Kafka Broker, or more precisely, the [Group Coordinator](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/kafka-coordinator-group-GroupCoordinator.html) that it consumed these messages. The coordinator is not interested in what you are actually doing with the data, it just wants to know if that particular Consumer Group was reading a message/offset or not.

Coming back to your questions...

> I am wondering whether there is another way to commit the failed records.

Although it doesn't look like you need it, but yes, there is another way of committing "failed" records. You can [enable auto commit](https://medium.com/@danieljameskay/understanding-the-enable-auto-commit-kafka-consumer-property-12fa0ade7b65). Together with the Consumer configuration auto.commit.interval.ms, you can periodically commit the offsets your consumer polled from the topic.

> Maybe it would be acceptable to not commit the failed records?

I don't have the knowledge of your particular use case, but it is acceptable to not commit the failed records. As mentioned above, the Group Coordinater is interested in the highest offset per partition that your consumer has consumed. If you consume a topic with 10 messages, you start reading from beginning and you only commit the 9th offset (offset counting starts at 0), then the next time you start your consumer it will ignore the first ten messages.

You could check out the Kafka internal topic __consumer_offsets to see what is stored for each Consumer Group: Topic, Partition, Offset (… among others).